# How to setup variable condition on qweb odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I have a line that sums all the values ​​above but i want to doesn't take values ​​with 'cancel' state

this is my python code for the definition of my state

```
sale_order_draft_ids = self.sale_order_draft_ids.ids
            sale_order_draft_ids = list(set(sale_order_draft_ids))

            sale_draft_ids = self.env['sale.order'].sudo().browse(sale_order_draft_ids)

            repartition_sales_d = {}

            for sale in sale_draft_ids:
                my_state = dict(self.env['sale.order']._fields['state'].selection).get(sale.state)

                repartition_sales_d[sale.id] = dict(
                    sale_draft_id=sale.id,
                    sale_number=sale.sale_number,
                    sale_name=sale.name,
                    sale_title=sale.sale_title,
                    sale_state=my_state,
                    sale_amount=sale.amount_untaxed,
                    sale_paid=sale.invoice_amount_total,
                    date_order=sale.date_order,
                )

            values['repartition_sales_d'] = repartition_sales_d
```

This is what i tried but doesnt work and i dont understand

```
<t t-if="sale['sale_state'] != 'cancel'">
<tr>
    <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:white !important;color:white;">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:white !important;color:white;">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:white !important;color:white;"/>
    <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:#171c8f !important;color:white;">
            <t t-set="sum_amount_and_report" t-value="sum_amount_and_report+ sum_amount + sum_report"/>
            <t t-esc="'{:,}'.format(int(sum_amount_and_report)).replace(',', ' ')"/> €
    </td>
    <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:#171c8f !important;color:white;">
            <t t-esc="'{:,}'.format(int(sum_paid)).replace(',', ' ')"/> €
    </td>
    <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:#171c8f !important;color:white;">
        <t t-if="sum_amount > 0">
            <t t-set="sum_percent" t-value="(sum_paid/sum_amount) * 100"/>
        </t>
        <t t-esc="'{:,}'.format(int(sum_percent)).replace(',', ' ')"/> %
    </td>
    <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:#171c8f !important;color:white;"/>
    </tr>
    </t>
</t>
```

This is the full template asked of my qweb, i tried a lot of thing but nothing worked i would like to understand. Every time i got the same error " raise QWebException("Error to render compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
Exception "

```
                                            <t t-set="sum_amount_and_report" t-value="0"/>
                                            <t t-set="sum_amount" t-value="0"/>
                                            <t t-set="sum_report" t-value="0"/>
                                            <t t-set="sum_paid" t-value="0"/>
                                            <t t-set="sum_percent" t-value="0"/>
                                            <t t-set="sale_percent" t-value="0"/>
                                            <t t-set="sale_paid" t-value="0"/>
                                            <t t-if="repartition_sales_d">
                                                <t t-foreach="repartition_sales_d" t-as="sale_draft_id">
                                                    <t t-set="sale" t-value="repartition_sales_d[sale_draft_id]"/>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="text-center">
                                                            <a t-attf-href="/web#id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;active_id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;model=sale.order&amp;view_type=form&amp;cids=&amp;menu_id=98">
                                                                <t t-esc="sale['sale_number']"/>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="text-center">
                                                            <a t-attf-href="/web#id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;active_id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;model=sale.order&amp;view_type=form&amp;cids=&amp;menu_id=98" style="text-decoration: none !important;color:#666666;">
                                                                <t t-esc="sale['date_order']"/>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="text-center">
                                                            <a t-attf-href="/web#id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;active_id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;model=sale.order&amp;view_type=form&amp;cids=&amp;menu_id=98" style="text-decoration: none !important;color:#666666;">
                                                                <t t-esc="sale['sale_title']"/>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="text-center">
                                                            <t t-set="sum_amount" t-value="sum_amount + int(sale['sale_amount'])"/>
                                                            <a t-attf-href="/web#id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;active_id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;model=sale.order&amp;view_type=form&amp;cids=&amp;menu_id=98" style="text-decoration: none !important;color:#666666;">
                                                                <t t-esc="'{:,}'.format(int(sale['sale_amount'])).replace(',', ' ')"/> €
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="text-center">
                                                            <t t-set="sum_paid" t-value="sum_paid + int(sale['sale_paid'])"/>
                                                            <a t-attf-href="/web#id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;active_id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;model=sale.order&amp;view_type=form&amp;cids=&amp;menu_id=98" style="text-decoration: none !important;color:#666666;">
                                                                <t t-esc="'{:,}'.format(int(sale['sale_paid'])).replace(',', ' ')"/> €
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="text-center">
                                                            <t t-if="int(sale['sale_amount']) > 0">
                                                                <t t-set="sale_percent" t-value="int(sale['sale_paid']) / (int(sale['sale_amount'])) * 100"/>
                                                            </t>
                                                            <a t-attf-href="/web#id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;active_id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;model=sale.order&amp;view_type=form&amp;cids=&amp;menu_id=98" style="text-decoration: none !important;color:#666666;">
                                                                <t t-esc="'{:,}'.format(int(sale_percent)).replace(',', ' ')"/> %
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="text-center">
                                                            <a t-attf-href="/web#id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;active_id=#{sale['sale_draft_id']}&amp;model=sale.order&amp;view_type=form&amp;cids=&amp;menu_id=98" style="text-decoration: none !important;color:#666666;">
                                                                <t t-if="sale['sale_state'] != 'cancel'">
                                                                    <t t-esc="sale['sale_state']"/>
                                                                </t>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </t>
                                            </t>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:white !important;color:white;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:white !important;color:white;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:white !important;color:white;"/>
                                                <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:#171c8f !important;color:white;">
                                                        <t t-set="sum_amount_and_report" t-value="sum_amount_and_report+ sum_amount + sum_report "/>
                                                        <t t-esc="'{:,}'.format(int(sum_amount_and_report)).replace(',', ' ')"/> €
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:#171c8f !important;color:white;">
                                                        <t t-esc="'{:,}'.format(int(sum_paid)).replace(',', ' ')"/> €
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:#171c8f !important;color:white;">
                                                    <t t-if="sum_amount > 0">
                                                        <t t-set="sum_percent" t-value="(sum_paid/sum_amount) * 100"/>
                                                    </t>
                                                    <t t-esc="'{:,}'.format(int(sum_percent)).replace(',', ' ')"/> %
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;font-weight:bold;padding-top:10px;background-color:#171c8f !important;color:white;"/>
                                            </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either change the `my_state` expression to:

```
my_state = sale.state
```

Or change the condition in the QWEB template to:

```
<t t-if="sale['sale_state'] != 'Cancelled'">
```

***Edit:***

You used `sale` variable outside the `t-if`, Odoo will always try to get a value from `sale` and if `repartition_sales_d` is not defined it will raise an error.

The `sum_amount_and_report` variable has not been initialized, Odoo will raise an error. You need to initialize it before:

```
<t t-set="sum_amount_and_report" 
   t-value="sum_amount_and_report+ sum_amount + sum_report"/>
```

Comment: Hey! I tried to initialized the all the variables but nothings changed sadly :/

Comment: Add `<t t-set="sum_amount_and_report" t-value="0.0"/>` after `<t t-set="sale_paid" t-value="0"/>` . The last `tr` depends on the value of `sale_state`, try to move it inside the `t-foreach`

Comment: Ok, i tried and i got somthing, i wanted to have a row who sum everthings inside the first <tr>, and after tried what u said i got a row below each 'repartition_sale_d'

Comment: Ok, you have just to remove the condition from the second row since it depends only on the values you initialized at the same level and keep the initialization of the sum_amount_and_report variable. You should probably exclude so with the cancel state inside the first row (sum).

Comment: Which condition should i remove ? i dont understand

Comment: The condition before the second row (tr): `<t t-if="sale['sale_state'] != 'cancel'">`

Comment: I tried last time, thats create me a row who sum but doesnt exclude the sale with cancel state

Comment: You need to exclude the sale with the cancel state inside the first row

Comment: I did/modify this in the first tr but doesnt work :/ <t t-if="sale['sale_state'] != 'cancel'"><t t-esc="sale['sale_state']"/></t>

Comment: Use `Cancelled` instead of `cancel`. To be able to use `cancel`,  replace `my_state` variable declaration in Python code with `my_state = sale.state`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250371/discussion-between-rizu-and-kenly).